# logrotate произвольного файла

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер, cron

В Кроне имеется задача запускать go скрипт каждые пол часа и писать в totallogs.log
В `/etc/logrotate.conf` создаю путь к файлу totallogs.log

```
/home/user/sync/totallogs.log{
rotate 30
size = 10M
missingok
notifempty
compress
maxage 30
}
```

Суть в том чтобы файл totallogs.log после 30 дней или если становится больше 10Мб бэкапировать, бэкап сохранять в течении 12 месяцев(1год), а файл totallogs.log делать пустым или на крайний случай просто удалять после 30 дней или при размере больше 10Мб
Вопросы:
1. Нужно ли в кроне делать еще что то для запуска
2. Если он автоматом будет запускаться тогда как сделать очищение этого файла после отработке logrotate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

прежде всего:

> бэкапировать, бэкап

программа *logrotate* не предназначена для создания и/или хранения резервных копий. она предназначена для (перевожу из `$ man logrotate`) «ротации, сжатия и отправки по почте системных логов».

> 1. Нужно ли в кроне делать еще что то для запуска

по умолчанию — нет: в пакет *logrotate* входит файл `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`, благодаря которому программа *crond* ежедневно запускает программу *logrotate*.

> 2. Если он автоматом будет запускаться, тогда как сделать очищение этого файла после отработки logrotate

программа *logrotate* по умолчанию **переименовывает** указанный вами файл.
если этот файл дополнительно «очищать», то теряется смысл хранения целых тридцати последовательных экземпляров файла (`rotate 30`) — они ведь будут пустые.

> Суть в том чтобы файл totallogs.log после 30 дней

интервал тридцать дней не соответствует ни одному из понимаемых программой *logrotate* интервалов — `daily` (по умолчанию), `weekly`, `monthly` и `yearly`. если месячный интервал вам подходит, то так и укажите в конф. файле. если же не подходит — придётся воспользоваться, например, `prerotate`-скриптом, вычисляющим нужное количество дней (описание тянет на отдельный вопрос).

> после 30 дней или если становится больше 10Мб бэкапировать, бэкап сохранять в течении 12 месяцев(1год)

директива `maxsize` «перекрывает» действие директивы с указанием интервала. т.е. в течение года у вас может накопиться более двенадцати (если вы выберете интервал `monthly`) экземляров. значит, использовать директиву `rotate` нельзя (она определяет максимальное количество сохраняемых файлов), а надо использовать директиву `maxage`, указав в ней, например, 365 (дней).

> файл totallogs.log делать пустым или на крайний случай просто удалять

про это я уже писал выше. повторюсь: *logrotate* не «делает пустым» и не удаляет указанный файл, а **переименовывает** его. если процесс, в него пишущий, работает постоянно, не закрывая файловый дескриптор, то процессу надо как-то «дать знать», чтобы он переоткрыл дескриптор. насколько я понял, для вашей программы (запускаемой периодически) это неактуально.

Comment: А разве после прохода logrotate он не будет создавать 30 копий? 
Суть в том чтобы файл totallogs.log после 30 дней в него записей бэкапировать, бэкап сохранять а файл totallogs.log делать пустым или на крайний случай просто удалять

Comment: внесите эту существенную информацию (противоречающую приведённому содержимому файла) в текст вопроса. после этого я дополню ответ.

Comment: Описание дополнил

Comment: Если необходимо, то `logrotate` может и «делать пустым» см. `copytruncate`. Но ТС'у это наверняка не нужно...

Comment: В целом понял. Поправьте если ошибаюсь, тогда я делаю maxage 365 size = 10M - Значит что когда файл будет больше 10Мб он файл totallogs.log  ротует и переименовывает. 
Как только logrotate завершен, totallogs.log файл не будет существовать?

Comment: @Den, файл будет **переименован** в `totallogs.log.1`

Comment: Сделал файл исчез, а где хранятся бэкапы?

Comment: @Den, наконец-то понял, что меня смущало в вашем вопросе. слово «бэкапы». программа *logrotate* не предназначена для создания и хранения резервных копий. по поводу местонахождения: по умолчанию файлы переименовываются, но не перемещаются в какие-либо каталоги.

Comment: Нет я  не храню бэкапы базы. Мне просто нужно чтобы файл с логами после 10Мб как бы резался, т.е. хранил эти логи в других файлах(файле) а файл totallogs.log становился пустым или исчезал.

 Добавил olddir /home/user/sync/logsbackup
Чтобы он сюда складывал, но ничего не происходит.

Comment: цитирую: «в пакет logrotate входит файл /etc/cron.daily/logrotate, благодаря которому программа crond ежедневно запускает программу logrotate». если у вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Comment: Убрал галочку конечного ответа, т.к. в основном вопросе написано что имеется необходимость хранения старых данных. Я не силен в познаниях Линукса поэтому могу быть излишне неподкованным. Ротация я так понимаю делает архивацию, значит и архивы сохраняются, значит и должна быть возможность эти архивы сложить в необходимую директорию.