# Перенос содержимого лога в архивный файл. Linux

Tags: linux, bash, логирование, iptables

Есть правило в iptables, которое логирует nat.

`conntrack -F
conntrack -E -o timestamp -p tcp -e NEW 2>&1 >> /var/log/iptables_nat_tcp &`

Но данных очень много и файл лога `/var/log/iptables_nat_tcp` быстро заполняется.

Задача уменьшать размер лога каждый день, перенося содержимое лога в новый архивный файл.

Пока я пытался грубо скриптом.

`mv iptables_nat_tcp /var/log/iptables/iptables_nat_tcp.$(date +%F-%T)
conntrack -F
conntrack -E -o timestamp -p tcp -e NEW 2>&1 >> /var/log/iptables_nat_tcp &`

Работает, но я не уверен, что это правильно.

Подскажите как быть.

Comment: используй `logrotate`, Люк...

Comment: а ещё есть ipt-netflow с nat-events

Comment: вы сделали практически всё необходимое для того, чтобы передать управление процессом программе logrotate. [см. например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/788163/178576).

Comment: Решил через logrotate, спасибо